# How to choose best combination of variables -

Tags: optimization, combinations, genetic-algorithm

I work on a marketing dataset : multivariate time series. For my input, I have different categorical features (binary classes : 0 and 1 ) and output=some marketing KPIs. I want to know which combination of features is the best strategy to inhance my output. I read in some forums about genetic algorithms but I don't know if it is a good method to use in my case.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Any generic learning algorithm that works with categorical data could be successful here, hard to say without a bit more information about the features etc. One place to start might be to use a [regression tree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html) and see how well it works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My features of Input describe which media channel X to use in the marketing adverstising strategy. So we have as features (TV, Radio ... ). Values={1: we use at the date t the media channel X, 0: whereas }. 
I used Tree regressor and then Shap values but it isolates the impact of my features (even with shap.dependence_plot I couldn't have good insights). 
What I want really is to predict the best combination of features to enhance my output.